# Loadrunner - Is it possible to increase the number of users for various scripts on the fly

Tags: loadrunner

I have a request to ramp up to 100 users in 30 minutes and then while in steady state increase the number of users to 150 - can this be done in a single test? Appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want but you could have 2 groups which are running the same script, setup the first group to ramp up (100 Vusers) to run and then setup the second group to ramp up (50)  as desired you just need to change the option you use for scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

while running the test, go to Vuser - add users and it pop up another screen - here you have your selected script with LG and quantity to add user. go ahead and add the user. those user will be in DOWN status. you need to start the user from the VUSER screen....
make sure you have DATA in your scripts so that it support 150 more user.

another way to do it is....as somebody else suggested.....add same script twice with two different group...and set the second script to start after your whole test finish. after 30 min into the test....start the user manually from Vuser screen

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, i know this comes way late but it is possible. 
Select the design tab at the bottom of your controller, then your script in the scenario groups section, now under scenario schedule graph there should be the interactive schedule graph. Make sure your script has a duration before continuing. so, click your script in the the interactive schedule graph and then click the pencil icon in the same area.
You will notice the three icons before the pencil icon become active. 
click on your script in the graph and click the middle icon to split the actions, you can then drag them to form a graph of your liking that will ramp up and down the users. When done you can click the pencil/edit icon again, you will notice that the global schedule on you left will have a number of new actions to ramp up and ramp down users ...

Answer (score 0):

schedule different groups with distinct start times, including your last group to ramp up after a steady state has been achieved

Answer (score 0):

You can step up or step down vuser count at any point of time during load test. Based on your license you can reach upto 10000 vuser counts to maintain concurrency in your test